# Por que no se pasa el id mediante POST en mi form de actualizar

Tags: php

**Actualizar usuario**

Este form recibe por parametro de url un **id** `?id=usuario_id`

```
                <form  action="../procedimientos/actualizarUsuario.php" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>ID</label>
                    <input type="number" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" value="<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>" disabled>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $usuario['nombre'] ?>" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                    <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" id="apellidos" value="<?php echo  $usuario['apellidos'] ?>"  placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo  $usuario['email'] ?>"  placeholder="Introduce tu email">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="<?php echo  $usuario['password'] ?>"  placeholder="Introduce una contraseña">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>Pais</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pais" class="form-control" id="pais" value="<?php echo  $usuario['pais'] ?>"  placeholder="Introduce tu pais">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label>Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                    <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] ?>"  id="fecha_nacimiento">
                  </div>


                  <button type="submit" class=" mt-2 btn btn-info">Editar Usuario</button>

            </form>
```

se rellenan todos los campos sim problema segun el id del usuario que le pases. Ahora bien si quiero actualizar no me pasa el **id** mediante **POST**,  mi form llama a este **fichero.php**:

`actualizarUsuario.php`

```
<?php 
    include_once 'conexion.php';



    if (
        isset($_POST['id']) and 
        isset($_POST['nombre']) and 
        isset($_POST['apellidos']) and 
        isset($_POST['email']) and  
        isset($_POST['password']) and 
        isset($_POST['pais']) and  
        isset($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']) ) {




                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $pais = $_POST['pais'];
                $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];


                var_dump($id);
                var_dump($nombre);
                var_dump($apellidos);
                var_dump($email);
                var_dump($password);
                var_dump($pais);
                var_dump($fecha_nacimiento);

                $sql = "UPDATE usuarios 
                SET 
                nombre='$nombre', 
                apellidos='$apellidos', 
                email='$email', 
                password='$password', 
                pais='$pais', 
                fecha_nacimiento='$fecha_nacimiento' 
                WHERE id = $id";


                var_dump($sql);


                // $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                // var_dump($result);


                // header("location: ../vistas/listar.php");


    }


 ?>
```

El problema esta cuando le paso el **id**, osea , cuando en el if de comprobacion meto el `isset($_GET['id])` que como no lo encuentra no hace nada. No entiendo porque si se lo estoy pasando como los demas campos que **SI** funcionan.

Comment: Tienes el campo disabled y los disabled no se envian.

Comment: Y si lo pongo en `style="display:none;"` se envia ?

Comment: Creo recordar que como hidden si se envía y esa es la mejor opción.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias. Me queda la duda de que cualquiera que se meta en el el html de la pagina pueda quitar el hidden y saber el id, cual es la forma de impedir eso ?

Comment: Pues depende como llegues al formulario pero tendrias que hacer que se guarde en session el id que se este actualizando.

Comment: ah vale vale, claro de la forma que yo estoy haciendolo no tiene cabida la session , pero vale, entiendo que se haga con sesiones. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te menciona JDev, quita el disabled del input. Todos los inputs que estén deshabilitados de la vista son omitidos del request siempre.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" value="<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>">
```